# If X^2 is not significant but X is significant, do I have to remove X^2 and run again the regression analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, nonlinear

Model DV ~ W+PDSR+Corr+(FAGDP1+FAGDP2)+log(PCGDP)+Exp+Pop+Health
FAGDP2=FAGDP1^2
Result:[image: Result with nonlinear term]

After removing FAGDP2(FAGDP1^2) from the model, FAGDP1 turns to be insignificant
[image: Result with only the linear specification]

Am I right in removing FAGDP^2 ?

Answer (score 6):

Quite generally, insignificant variables do *not* have to be removed from regression models (this also holds for parameters belonging to terms such as $X^2$). Also, generally, standard regression tests are invalid in models that stem from data driven selection.

Comment: The OP could use  a simultaneous test of $X$ & $X^2$ together to determine if the variable is associated with $Y$, should that be of interest.

Comment: @Lewian! this is a FE regression by the way! the rationale behind including the X2 term is to see whether there is a non-linear effect of the FAGDP variable. So, now that it is insignificant. Why do you think I should keep it?

Comment: Reinstate Monica ! What OP stands for?

Comment: OP means "original poster", i.e., you.

Comment: @amnaymehlaoui: I'm not saying you should keep it. There may be reason to get rid of it, particularly if the aim of the exercise was in the first place to find out whether you need it. I cannot tell you what you should do as I don't know anything about the background.  I was just answering to your original question whether you *have to* remove it based on insignificance, and the answer is no. This doesn't mean you *have to* keep it. However, as I wrote, if you kick it out, p-values of the model resulting from this are invalid.